# How to validate a form with yup and formik?

Tags: javascript, yup

I have a form with schema like this.

```js
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      date: Yup.string()
        .required("Required!"),
      time: Yup.string()
        .required("Required!")
})
```

I need to validate whether this form is used to set a new date or update an existing date.

If the form is used to update an existing date, I want to notify the user if they can't change the time 30 minutes before or 30 minutes after from the preset time.

For example, if preset time is 8AM.
User can't change time to 7:30 or 8:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve by add new indentifier to form

```js
const ComponentWithFormik = withFormik({
  validationSchema,
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => {
    return {
      id: props.id,
      date, 
      time
    }
  }
})
```

Then add id to schema

```js
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      id: string(),
      date: Yup.string()
        .required("Required!"),
      time: Yup.string()
        .required("Required!")
})
```

From the id, I know wheather is form is used to set new date or update existing date.

Finally just use `.when` method.
My code look like this.

```js
validationSchema: Yup.object({
      date: Yup.string()
        .required("Required!"),
      time: Yup.string()
        .required("Required!")
        .when('id' => {
          id: id => id !== undefined,
          then: string().test(
            'time',
            'error message',
            function(value){  
              //put logic here
              //to access sibling value use this.parent
            }
          )
        })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use `yup.addMethod()` function [docs link](https://github.com/jquense/yup#yupaddmethodschematype-schema-name-string-method--schema-void)

Here this [article](https://medium.com/@arkadyt/how-does-yup-addmethod-work-creating-custom-validation-functions-with-yup-8fddb71a5470) can help you.

Comment: You should provide some context to your answer, links can die/expire.

Comment: you can always google `yup.addMetod` and read the documentation of that function.

Answer (score 1):

`MomentJs` is a great tool for working with dates.

You can add a test `function` to the validation chain.

```js
validationSchema: Yup.object({
    date: Yup.string().required("Required!"),
    time: string()
        .test(
            "time-range",
            "error message",
            (value) =>
                moment().diff(moment(value), "minutes") > 30 ||
                moment().diff(moment(value), "minutes") < 30
        )
        .required("Required!"),
});
```